# Minimize a non-linear function with two variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, nonlinear-system

Let $g,h \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ symmetric. I am having the following two variable function

$$f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2} g^T\left(A + \frac{xy}{2}I\right)^{-1}g+\frac{x}{6}y^3 \tag{1}$$ with $x\geq 0$, $ y>0$, $g = -\left(A + \frac{xy}{2}I\right)h $ and $h \neq 0$. Let also

$$h(x,y) = - \left(A + \frac{xy}{2}I\right)^{-1} g,\tag{2}$$ where $g$ the actual constant vector.

To minimize $(1)$, I took the first derivative w.r.t. $x$ and $y$, and set them equal to zero, i.e.,

$$\begin{aligned}\partial_x f(x,y)= -\frac{y}{4} g^T\left(A + \frac{xy}{2}I\right)^{-2}g+\frac{y^3}{6} = -\frac{y}{4} ||h(x,y)||^2 + \frac{y^3}{6} = & 0 \Leftrightarrow \\ -\frac{y}{2}\left( \frac{||h(x,y)||^2}{2} - \frac{y^2}{3}\right) = &0\end{aligned}\tag{3}$$
and
$$\begin{aligned} \partial_y f(x,y)= -\frac{x}{4} g^T\left(A + \frac{xy}{2}I\right)^{-2}g+\frac{x}{2}y^2 = -\frac{x}{4} ||h(x,y)||^2 + \frac{xy^2}{2} = 0 & \Leftrightarrow \\  -\frac{x}{2}\left(\frac{||h(x,y)||^2 }{2} - y^2\right) = &0,\end{aligned}\tag{4}$$

where $$g^T\left(A + \frac{xy}{2}I\right)^{-2} g = \left[g^T\left(A + \frac{xy}{2}I\right)^{-1}\right] \left[\left(A + \frac{xy}{2}I\right)^{-1} g\right] = {||h(x,y)||^2} \tag{5}$$ is used.

What bothers me is the optimization procedure. Suppose, for a fixed $x$ we have solved the non-linear equation $||h(x,y)|| = \sqrt{2}/\sqrt{3}y$ to get $y$. Then, given $y$, from $(3)$, $x$ can be either zero or can be computed by solving $||h(x,y)|| = \sqrt{2} y$.

Even taking the derivatives and setting them to zero is an intuitive approach I found the optimization procedure strange enough. Could you please someone give some suggestions on a more appropriate way to solve (1)?

PS: In this case is it more preferable to use an black box root finder?

**EDIT1:** After @Joe comment I have tried to write the above equations using $u=-\frac{xy}{2}$ and $v=y$. Using this we have

$$f(u,v) = \frac{1}{2} g^T\left(A - u\:I\right)^{-1}g-\frac{uv^2 }{3}, \quad v \neq 0, \quad u \geq 0 \tag{6}$$

$$h(u,v) = - \left(A - u\:I\right)^{-1} g, \quad g \neq 0 \tag{7}$$

$$\partial_u f(u,v) = \frac{1}{2} ||h(u,v)||^2 - \frac{v^2}{3}, \quad h(u,v) \neq 0 \tag{8}$$

$$\partial_v f(u,v) = -\frac{2}{3}uv \tag{9}$$

**EDIT2:** Using the diagonalization @Joe suggested, i.e.,$A = O\Lambda O^T$ where $\Lambda$ a diagonal and $O$ orthogonal, we can write

$$f(u, v) = \frac{1}{2} ||O(\Lambda -u \:I)^{-1/2}O^Tg||^2 - \frac{1}{3}uv^2 \tag{10} $$.

Comment: Your notation makes absolutely no sense to me.  $x$ and $y$ are scalar variables. What in the world is $g$ and why does $g^\top$ appear?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin i did some edit. Any comments to understand the nature of the problem are highly welcome.

Comment: Makes no sense. $x$ and $y$ are scalar variables. If $A$ is a matrix, what does $A+xy/2$ mean?

Comment: @TedShifrin I hope now to make sense. Any help on how to solve it is highly appreciated.

Comment: Which vector, $g$ or $h$, is actually a constant vector? This is very hard to decipher.

Comment: @TedShifrin thanks for the interest, $g$ is the actual constant vector.

Comment: OK, so your differentiation is wrong, since you treated $h$ as constant. I suggest you forget $h$ and leave it in terms of $g$. The matrix expression will need to be differentiated (correctly).

Comment: Warning: Unless $A$ is symmetric, you cannot go from $g^\top (A-xyI/2)^{-2}g$ to $\|(A-xyI/2)g\|^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change variables to $u = -xy/2, v = y$. This co-ordinate transformation is invertible, so it's fine to minimise in $u,v$ and transform back to $x,y$ after. Then you see that $$f(u,v) = g^T(A-uI)^{-1}g/2 - u v^2/3.$$ Note that $\det(A-uI)=0$ whenever $u$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, and hence non invertible for some set of discrete values of $u$.

This means that for general $A$ you should not expect to be able to minimise $f$. For example, let $d=1$. Then $$f(u,v) =\frac{1}{2} \frac{g^2}{A-u} - u v^2/3,$$ which has a simple pole when $u=A$. So this function is unbounded from below and has no minimum.

For $d>1$, it will depend on the geometric multiplicities of your eigenvalues. If your matrix has all eigenvalues of even multiplicity then I believe you will get poles of the form $1/(\lambda-u)^{2n}$, in which case a minimum may exist. If you have any eigenvalues with odd multiplicities then your $f$ would be unbounded from below. So you need to look at the spectrum of eigenvalues of your $A$; most matrices $A$ would produce an $f$ with no minimum.

Edit;
I notice that you have now got $x\ge 0$ and $y>0$, and $A$ symmetric. Symmetric $A$ is diagonalisable, and hence has no second order poles in the expansion of $(A-uI)^{-1}$. However the restrictions on $x$ and $y$ may mean that the poles all fall outside of this region, which would be necessary for a minimum of your function to exist. To make further progress with this problem, it would be necessary to have further information about the spectrum of eigenvalues of $A$. Maybe it would be sufficient to know that they were all positive or negative, although I'd need to think about this.

Diagonalize $A$ with an orthogonal matrix $O$ such that $A=ODO^T$, where $D$ has the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ of $A$ along its diagonal. Define $w=O^T g$. Then your $f$ can be written as $$f(u,v) = w^T(D-uI)^{-1}w/2 - u v^2/3.$$ Now we can expand the sum because $D$ is diagonal to arrive at $$f(u,v) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^d \frac{w_i^2}{\lambda_i -u} - u v^2/3.$$ It is necessary to know that all of the poles in this expression lie outside of the region which you want to minimise in for a minimum to exist.

Edit2:
Suppose that $A$ has all positive eigenvalues. Now look for points where the gradient of $f$ is 0;
$$\partial_u f =\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^d \frac{w_i^2}{(\lambda_i -u)^2} - v^2/3$$ and $$ \partial_v f = -2u v/3=0.$$

This is equivalent to a set of simultaneous polynomial equations. The second equation is solved either by $u=0$ or $v=0$. So firstly we see that there are two solutions of the form $$u=0, v =\pm\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}\sum_{i=1}^d \frac{w_i^2}{(\lambda_i)^2}}.$$Based on the fact that you want $y=v>0$, you can throw away the negative square root here.

It is also possible to solve this equation by setting $v=0$, which is different from the 1d case I described in the comments. In that case you would have a polynomial equation to solve, after multiplying through by all of the denominators in the following equation $$\sum_{i=1}^d \frac{w_i^2}{(\lambda_i -u)^2}=0.$$ if you are having trouble understanding this, try setting $d=2$ and then $d=3$, and look at the equation in both cases. Given that you asked for $v>0$ in your question, you may not be interested in this, however this could mean that the minimum of the function lies along $v=0$ and hence no minium exists for $v>0$.

In all cases, solving for $\partial_u f = \partial_v f = 0$ is not a necessary or sufficient condition for $f$ to be minimised at these points; you will need to look at these points and check if they are minima, maxima or saddle points, and also look along the boundaries $u=0$ and $v=0$ in case the function is minimised here.

Comment: Thanks for the interest. I am looking at the function $f(u, v)$. I we compute $\partial_u f(u, v) = 0 \Leftrightarrow  \frac{1}{2} \frac{g^2}{(A-u)^2} + v^2/3 = 0$, which is only possible if $g=0$ and $v=0$ or if $g=0$ and $r=0$. However, this contradicts the assumptions on  $g\neq0$ and $r\neq0$ which indicates that there is no solution. Am I missing something?

Comment: @darkmoor, I think your reasoning is roughly in the right direction. You need to calculate both $\partial_u f$ and $\partial_v f$ and then solve for both of these equal to zero as simultaneous equations in $u$ and $v$ to look for a minimum point of a function in 2 dimensions. What is the $r$? I didn't understand where this came from

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I wanted to write $y=0$.

Comment: Ok well, in this case I find $\partial_u f =\frac{1}{2} \frac{g^2}{(A-u)^2} - v^2/3=0$ and $\partial_v f = -2 u v/3=0$. If we solve the second equation with $v=0$ then the first equation has no solution for $u$. Instead solve the second equation with $u=0$, then we find that $v=\pm\frac {g}{A}\sqrt{3/2}$ solves the first equation. However these two points $(0,\pm\frac {g}{A}\sqrt{3/2})$ are not necessarily minima, only stationary points. In this case they are not minima because we can see from the form of $f$ that it is unbounded below.

Comment: Thanks for you comments. I have tried to reformulate my post using your transformation. The solution suggests that $u$ has to be always zero when we solve $f(u, v)$? I am asking because in my problem, I must have $x \geq 0$ and $y > 0$ which indicates that after your transformation I must have  $u \leq 0$. Could you please provide some verification-clarification?

Comment: @Darkmoor, oh I didn't see the restriction to $x\ge 0$ and $y>0$, that's important and it means a minimum could exist. However, as I have explained, this will be dependent on the spectrum of eigenvalues of $A$. It seems to me that you are attempting minimise this problem for a general matrix $A$. I believe I have provided a proof that this is not possible. To make further progress with this problem it would be necessary for you to provide information about the eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: Thanks, $A$ is a symmetric matrix with positive and negative (indefinite) eigenvalues. In my problem it is a Hessian. To solve something like $||h(x,y)||=y$ with $x$ or $y$ fixed is possible using Trust Region methodology, you can see [here](https://books.google.gr/books?id=wfs-hsrd4WQC&printsec=frontcover&hl=el&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) section 7. I just mention because I was trying to formulate the system in such a way in order to use this machinery. Just mention it in case it helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133083/discussion-between-joe-and-darkmoor).

Comment: I think there is machinery to solve the last expression you mention about f(u,v) when $u$ or $v$ is fixed. Please see Section 7.3, e.q. 7.3.2 in the link. The author, ends up to find the roots of $||s(\lambda)||-\Delta =0$ in Sec 7.3.2. That is why I have tried to introduce this type of equation in the system of equations. However, this system confuses me on how we can compute both (x,y) or (u,v) in the transformed case.

Comment: @Darkmoor, as far as I can see I have provided a proof that this function will only have a minimum in the region you are interested in if $A$ has all positive eigenvalues. Introducing more sophisticated methods will not change this. I encourage you to spend some more time thinking about this problem on your own. If you don't find the methods I have introduced to be helpful, then try to rephrase a new clearer question which references the source you mentioned and repost that, either here or on mathoverflow. You need to work on how you present your arguments, often it's not easy to follow them.

Comment: Sorry for asking again. You said "function will only have a minimum in the region you are interested in if  has all positive eigenvalues" I do not see how positive eigenvalues will guarantee a minimum. Also, in you edit you mention that in order to have a minimum  poles have to be outside the region we want to minimize. So, if we have $u < \lambda_{\min}$ and $y > 0$ will that guarantee a minimum? Given this region can we write a more analytical solution about the optimal $(u, v)$? Is it possible to address my questions in you post?

Comment: Look at the final form that I have written as a sum over eigenvalues. If all $\lambda_i$ are positive, then the poles will be for $u>0$. You need the poles to lie outside of the region you are minimising over for a minium to exist. If you're having trouble understanding this, fix $d=2$ and $v=w_1=w_2=1$, and then you have a simple function in $u$. Sketch this function and look for minima, depending on whether $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are positive or negative

Comment: @Darkmoor I have edited my answer one last time. I had a quick think about how $||h(x,x)|| = y$ fits into this but it was not obvious to me. I will not spend any more time on this problem. Try breaking down your problem into smaller questions and asking these questions. Good luck.